# How do I simulate a keyboard enter button press in JavaScript/jquery that is not selector specific?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

I need a real, keyboard press simulation.Not one that is only selector specific. I need a way to simulate an actual enter button press on the keyboard, in JavaScript. This way the enter press will work the same every where i decide to trigger it , hence making it an actual enter button on a keyboard, simulation. Please help :) (I am using this in imacros and recording wont cut it because it is specific and not universal)

Comment: Can you provide some detail / context about what it is you are trying to do with this? If this is for testing, you may want to consider using a more realistic test environment like Selenium Webdriver.

Comment: Hello, I hope you are not the down voter. :D " I need a way to simulate an actual enter button press on the keyboard, in JavaScript" i am trying to build a keyboard that only has an enter button. :D

Comment: Nope, wasn't the downvoter. For a fake keyboard, since you probably have the input element handy that you are appending characters to, I would suggest simply calling the "click()" function on that input element. If you don't already have that element, document.activeElement may help.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, browsers won't allow you to simply simulate the pressing of a key from a browser context.  If this were possible, then a user could load a web page and the javascript on the web page could take over the keyboard and do nasty things to the computer.

For a more detailed explanation, as well as some alternatives, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events).